# JPEGImageWriteParam throws ClassCastException

Tags: java, image, awt, jpeg, javax.imageio

I am trying to compress an image in java with following piece of code

```
ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter)  ImageIO.getImageWritersByMIMEType("image/jpeg").next();
JPEGImageWriteParam param = (JPEGImageWriteParam) writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
param.setCompressionType("JPEG");
param.setCompressionQuality(0.2f);
param.setProgressiveMode( ImageWriteParam.MODE_DEFAULT );       

writer.setOutput(ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(outputStream));
writer.write(null, new IIOImage(resizedImg, null, null), param);
```

The second line `JPEGImageWriteParam param = (JPEGImageWriteParam) writer.getDefaultWriteParam();` throws `ClassCastException`.
And if I change it to `ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();`
it throws `UnsupportedOperationException` for the line `param.setProgressiveMode( ImageWriteParam.MODE_DEFAULT );`.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImageWriter#getDefaultWriteParam()` gives an object of type `ImageWriteParam` not `JPEGImageWriteParam` that's why you are getting class cast exception. What you should do instead is create a new `JPEGImageWriteParam` and use it.

```
JPEGImageWriteParam param = new JPEGImageWriteParam(<pass your lacale here>);
param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
param.setCompressionType("JPEG");
param.setCompressionQuality(0.2f);
param.setProgressiveMode( ImageWriteParam.MODE_DEFAULT );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your immediate reply . But can you be more specific on what need to be passed here `new JPEGImageWriteParam("?")` @Sanjeev

Comment: you have to pass object of class java.util.Locale .. for example you can pass Locale.US if you live in united states.

Comment: or you can pass Locale.getDefault () which will pick default as per your runtime settings

Comment: I know its kinda late but it helped me thanks @Sanjeev.... but instead of Locale i have passed null .... :)

Comment: Glad that helped you .. have fun coding :)